# Pivoting in a function

Tags: sql-server

I tried to make a function on the AdventureWorks2014 database for classifying customers to classes A, B and C for every year

```
    CREATE FUNCTION udf_CustomersClassification(@year int)
    RETURNS @TABLE TABLE (TOPRANK NVARCHAR(1), ID INT, FULLNAME NVARCHAR(MAX))
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TABLE
            SELECT  CASE
                        WHEN TOTAL > 100000 THEN 'A'
                        WHEN TOTAL > 50000 THEN 'B'
                        ELSE 'C'
                    END AS RN,
                    CustomerID,
                    FULLNAME
            FROM(
                SELECT  SOH.CustomerID,
                        PP.FirstName + ' ' + PP.LastName AS FULLNAME,
                        SUM(SOD.TOTALORDER) AS TOTAL,
                        YEAR(SOH.OrderDate) AS ORDERYEAR 
                FROM    (
                            SELECT  SalesOrderID, 
                                    SUM(OrderQty*UnitPrice) AS TOTALORDER
                            FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail
                            GROUP BY SalesOrderID
                        ) AS SOD
                JOIN    Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
                ON      SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
                JOIN    Sales.Customer AS C
                ON      SOH.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
                JOIN    Person.Person AS PP
                ON      C.PersonID = PP.BusinessEntityID
                WHERE   YEAR(SOH.OrderDate) = @year
                GROUP BY SOH.CustomerID, 
                        PP.FirstName + ' ' + PP.LastName,
                        YEAR(SOH.OrderDate)) AS A
            ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
        RETURN 
    END
    GO
```

then counting them in this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_CustomersClassOverYears(@startyear int, @endyear int)
RETURNS @TABLE TABLE(CLASS NVARCHAR(1), Cust_No INT, YEAR INT)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE @startyear <= @endyear
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TABLE
        SELECT  TOPRANK,
                COUNT(ID) AS Cust_Num, 
                @startyear AS YEAR
        FROM    udf_CustomersClassification(@startyear)
        GROUP BY TOPRANK
        ORDER BY TOPRANK, YEAR
    SET @startyear = @startyear + 1
    END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

then i tried this code and its working

```
SELECT CLASS, [2012], [2013], [2014] 
FROM udf_CustomersClassOverYears(2012, 2014) AS A
PIVOT(MAX(CUST_NO) 
        FOR YEAR 
            IN ([2012], [2013], [2014])) AS PVT
ORDER BY CLASS
```

[image]

the question is that i want to use this pivoting inside the last function and i can't because of the number of columns is not constant, its according to the start and end year parameter

Comment: Well you're not really pivoting in a function per se. You could just execute the function in dynamic sql. e.g. `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT CLASS, ' + @myCols + ' FROM udf_CustomersClassOverYears(' + CAST(@myMinCol AS CHAR(4)) + ', ' + CAST(@myMaxCol AS CHAR(4)) + ') AS A PIVOT(MAX(CUST_NO) FOR YEAR IN (' + @myCols + ')) AS PVT ORDER BY CLASS';` then get the variables (@myCols, @myMinCol, @myMaxCol) however you get them... (if a user inputs them, then all you need to do for mycols is get all the years in between)

Comment: Look up Dynamic PIVOT. http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/